# Generic class wrapper in scala

Tags: scala

Hello I would like to create a generic wrapper in scala in order to track the changes of the value of any type. I don't know/haven't found any other ways so far and I was thinking of creating a class and I've been trying to use the Dynamic but it has some limitations.

```
case class Wrapper[T](value: T) extends Dynamic {
  private val valueClass = value.getClass

  def applyDynamic(id: String)(parameters: Any*) = {
    val objectParameters = parameters map (x => x.asInstanceOf[Object])
    val parameterClasses = objectParameters map (_.getClass)
    val method = valueClass.getMethod(id, parameterClasses:_*)
    val res = method.invoke(value, objectParameters:_*)

    // TODO: Logic that will eventually create some kind of event about the method invoked.

    new Wrapper(res)
  }
}
```

With this code I have trouble when invoking the plus("+") method on two Integers and I don't understand why. Isn't there a "+" method in the Int class? The error I am getting when I try addition with both a type of Wrapper/Int is:

```
var wrapped1 = Wrapper(1)
wrapped1 = wrapped1 + Wrapper[2] // or just 2

type mismatch;
 found   : Wrapper[Int]/Int
 required: String
```

Why is it expecting a string?

If possible it would also be nice to be able to work with both the Wrapper[T] and the T methods seamlessly, e.g.

```
val a = Wrapper[Int](1)
val b = Wrapper[Int](2)
val c = 3

a + b // Wrapper[Int].+(Wrapper[Int])
a + c // Wrapper[Int].+(Int)
c + a // Int.+(Wrapper[Int])
```

Comment: You will eventually hit the fact that primitives are unboxed in Scala. I have written a 20 page paper on exactly what you are trying to do and this is just the tip of the iceberg. Depending on how far you want to go, you will hit a million different issues. The tl;dr this isn't really possible at a full extend without writing a compiler plugin to explicitly alter how certain stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if youre trying to make a proxy which will get any changes of desired values you'l probably fail without agents(https://dzone.com/articles/java-agent-1) because it will force you make code modifications for bytecode that accepts final classes and primitives to accept your proxy instead of that and it would require more than intercepting changes of "just class" but also all classes of members and produce origin-of-value analysis and so on. It's by no way trivial problem.

Another approach is to produce diffs of case classes by comparing classes in certain points of execution and there's generic implementation like that, it uses derivation for computing diffs: https://github.com/ivan71kmayshan27/ShapelesDerivationExample I believe you can came with easier solution with magnolia. Actualy this one is unable to work for just classes unless you write your own macro and have some problems regarding ordered and unordered collections.

Comment: The former will not work. Java's metaprogramming API clashes with a lot of things in Scala. Even in Java, proxies only work with interfaces and not concrete classes. I am not sure what you meant by the second part. My understanding is that the OP wants to hijack method calls to understand how a value evolves. The simplest example is that, this is not gonna be any use for primitives. Or did I misunderstood your remark?

Comment: Former will work because scala code transpiles down to bytecode like everything else and that's why you can use scala code from both kotlin and java, thus you can modify it using API that allows bytecode processors. You will still need to account for some scala things but saying "it won't work at all" is mostly incorrect. Second approach is the usage plain diffs of values rather than spying.

Comment: Not entirely true for Scala 3 but yeah that is outside of the scope of this question. I was simply going off the linked article. I was just trying to say the methodology presented there can not capture all the Scala constructs. There are ways of doing it but it gets out of hand really quickly.